# Make Calculations and Output result

Tags: reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am creating an App using Django and React. I would like the user to input several numeric values on the Frontend and based on these values to perform some calculations and output the result in the Frontend (also store the values in the database).

I am confused on where on the backend I should add the logic to perform the calculations. On views.py or admin.py or on another file?

I am currently trying to create the logic on the admin.py file but I am not sure if this will allow me to make the result visible on the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the calculation should be preformed in views.py and passed to the front end (for example by passing it as a dict )

```
result = number1 + number2    
content = {'result': result}
return render(request, 'app/file.html', context)
```

and then you can use it in a html file (that's an example you can pass the value elsewhere too) by using {{result}}

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am trying to use Django with React in Frontend. Therefore, I guess the process is different right? By the way, I also want to see the result in the admin page. Will that be possible?

Comment: if you want to see the result in the admin page, you could create a model that takes for example: 3 int values and returns the sum of them (so you would use 4 "models.IntegerField()" and 3 of them would be available for the user and the last one would just store the answer) [and honestly I haven't used react yet so I don't know if it is different but I will try to look up that]

Comment: as found in [link](https://www.saaspegasus.com/guides/modern-javascript-for-django-developers/integrating-django-react/)"The ability to pass data directly from Django to the front end is one major benefit of the hybrid architecture In a client-server architecture you have to either create additional APIs or repeat logic in the back end and front end
Here are the steps to the approach
In the Django view that serves our application we get the data we need
We pass it to the template in a way that can be serialized as JSON
We load the JSON into JavaScript and make it available to the front end

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It makes me understand things better. But lets say I want to show the result both in frontend and in the admin page. Do I need to write the logic(calculations) on both files?

Comment: the calculations would be done in views.py by using a model from models.py {because you want to show the result in admin page} so you need to write the calculation logic only in views {if you would need help in writing that app I can help you a bit and explain the logic to you}

Comment: Thanks a lot :) If I need any help I will let you know

Comment: I can send you a little project with comments that would show you how to work some thing out (just drop a mail or something)